# Participant Display Name with Twilio Programmable Video

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

Is it possible for local participant to change some data (in my use case, their display name) and have it accessible to other participants? I expected the Participant object to have some kind of metadata that can be changed locally, but I'm not seeing anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog with overlays that may be of interest, in this blog, it is used for display names.

[How to add an overlay to your web video chat](https://www.twilio.com/blog/add-an-overlay-to-web-video-chat)

Comment: I think that addresses a different case. I need for participants A, B and C to display a name edited by participant D.

Comment: That would be outside the SDK, no, since the SDK just has the identity, https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens.